# Find JavaScript function with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

take a look at my following regex: https://regex101.com/r/HMya54/2

I only want to find the javascript-function with "_tsid" in it, not all JavaScript functions, and to replace that whole function by an HTML-Comment `<!-- here was my function -->`.

I tried something like: `/<script.*?>([\s\S]*?)_tsid([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/` but that seems not the right way.

Can you help me with that problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Trying to parse JavaScript source with a regular expression is in general not going to be possible. You may have a special arrangement in your code, but you didn't post it. What does the relevant part of the source actually like? And what is it you want; *function with "_tsid" in it* is hard to understand.

Comment: My code is from my shopware-website. I want to exactly extract just that one javascript function (the third in the regex101.com example) and replace it by a string. So that the first javascript-functions still exists but my searched one is not. Hope that's a little bit better for understanding.

Comment: Replacing it is not going to do anything.

Comment: I want to replace that whole function by an HTML-Comment ("<!-- here was my function -->")

Comment: One alternative to what you have already done is using positive lookaroung regex: /(?<=<script>|<script type="text\/javascript">)[\S\s]+?(?=<\/script>)/gm
.In this case, you  capture what is inside the script tags, but not the tags.
Obs: lookaround only allows you to specify fixed length patterns, then we can't use <script.*?> inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use your current (or its optimized version, see below) and use a callback as the replacement argument where you can check if the match contains the string of your choice, and if it is there, perform the replacement:

```js
let text = '&lt;script type="text/javacript">alert("First one!");&lt;/script>\n\n&lt;script>console.log("Hello World");&lt;/script>\n\n&lt;script type="text/javascript">\n                (function () {\n                    var _tsid = \'XFE5AF4B9ADDACA0E60017B1BC4D16AE2\';\n                    _tsConfig = {\n                        \'yOffset\': \'0\', /* offset from page bottom */\n                        \'variant\': \'reviews\', /* reviews, default, custom, custom_reviews */\n                        \'customElementId\': \'\', /* required for variants custom and custom_reviews */\n                        \'trustcardDirection\': \'\', /* for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft */\n                        \'customBadgeWidth\': \'\', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */\n                        \'customBadgeHeight\': \'\', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */\n                        \'disableResponsive\': \'false\', /* deactivate responsive behaviour */\n                                                \'disableTrustbadge\': \'false\', /* deactivate Trustbadge® */\n                                                \'responsive\': {\n                            \'variant\': \'\', /* floating, custom */\n                            \'customElementId\': \'\' /* required for variant custom */\n                        }\n                    };\n                    var _ts = document.createElement(\'script\');\n                    _ts.type = \'text/javascript\';\n                    _ts.charset = \'utf-8\';\n                    _ts.async = true;\n                    _ts.src = \'//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/\' + _tsid + \'.js\';\n                    var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0];\n                    __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);\n                })();\n&lt;/script>';
text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/<script[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?script[\s>])[^<]*)*<\/script>/g, (x) => x.includes("_tsid") ? "<!-- here was my function -->" : x);
console.log(text);
```

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/HMya54/3) is now `/<script[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?script[\s>])[^<]*)*<\/script>/g`, it matches `<script`, anu zero or more chars other than `>`, then a `>`, then any zero or more non-`<` chars, then zero or more sequences of `<` not followed with an optional `/` and then `script` followed with a whitespace or `>` and then zero or more non-`<` chars, and then `</script>`, and then the text containing `_tsid` only is replaced, else, the match is reinserted into the resulting string.